# bzr: Softly undo last commit

Tags: git, repository, bazaar

How to revert the last commit and put the local changes into the workspace?

in Git I would do:

```
git reset --soft HEAD^
```

How can I do that in Bazaar?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The equivalent command in bazaar is: `bzr uncommit`